# If I have two magnets repelling each other, will they always form a peak in the middle?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetics, magnetic-flux, magnet

If I have two identical magnets, aligned so they repel each other a distance of X apart and at a height of Z I have Hall effect sensor, the peak of the magnetic field sensed will be at the distance X/2 away from each magnet.

What happens if I reduce the strength of the first magnet by 30%? Will the "magnetic center" move? Is there any way for me to calculate this without a FEM solver?

Every y value is 0 because it's all in a plane. everything is symmetrical.

[image]

Comment: `Is there any way for me to calculate this without a FEM solver?` ... what use is a `yes` answer?

Comment: may be a better fit at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions